# How do I prove the following projection is well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

$\pi_k: \prod G_i \to G_k$ defined by $\pi_k((g_i))=g_k$. Usually, to prove some $f$'s well definedness, show $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y).$ There's an obvious difficulty here, there can be many different sequence with the same $k$'th coordinate.

(The map is an epimorphism of groups.)

Comment: I don't see any difficulty. If two sequences are equal, they have the same $k$'th coordinate, and so their projection onto the $k$'th coordinate is the same. Of course there are ziliions of sequences with the same $k$'the coordinate, but they all have the same projection onto that coordinate, don't they?

Comment: $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$ is always true!

Comment: My initial reaction is...wait, what? I mean, just how many values can the the $k$-th entry in a sequence possibly have? Typically, questions of "well-definition" only come up when one uses a *representative* of a domain element to define a function. To see what I mean, suppose the indexing set is $\{1,2\}$. Is there really any question about what we mean by the first coordinate, and the second?